# what is the most performant way to filter out a single resource?

Tags: database, sparql, dbpedia

I'm using D3 to draw node graphs of things from DBPedia, and since `ontology:wikiPageWikiLink` comes up a lot, I've filtered it out using a simple `FILTER` statement:

```
FILTER (?_predicate != <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageWikiLink>)
```

And in the process, I've observed a noticeable increase in the query execution time when using that line.

So, is there more performant way to filter out the IRI?

Comment: If you want a triple where you don't care about what the predicate is (I'm guessing the `_` prefix is "ignore me") except that it's *not* dbpedia-owl:wikiPageWikiLink, can you just ask for that with the property path `?s ^dbpedia-owl:wikiPageWikiLink ?o`?  Then you'd be getting only the results you want rather than more and filtering out what you don't want.

Comment: Oops, there's a typo in the previous comment (fixed in the answer);  that should be `!dbpedia-owl:wikiPageWikiLink` not `^dbpedia-owl:wikiPageWikiLink`.  That is, the operator should be `!` (negation), not `^` (reverse).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a triple where you don't care about what the predicate is (I'm guessing the **_** prefix is "ignore me") except that it's *not* **dbpedia-owl:wikiPageWikiLink**, you could simply ask for that with the property path

```
?s !dbpedia-owl:wikiPageWikiLink ?o
```

Then you'd get just the results you want rather than getting more and filtering out what you don't want.

Comment: actually, it just donned on me that I may have misread your initial statement. I don't care what the predicate is, but I still want to be able to get a list of predicates and return the result bound to the variable `?_predicate`. Typically, I'd have a line that was something along the lines of `?s ?p ?o .` and that would've caught some predicates. But, if i'm using that spot to say `!something:somePredicate`, where do I put my variable so that way I have access to the predicates that met the notX condition?